# TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to pipe the stdout/stderr of a child process to `/dev/null`

I have this:

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');
...
k.stderr.pipe(fs.openSync('/dev/null', 'w'));
```

and I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: dest.on is not a function
```

anyone know how to explicitly send stdout/stderr to `/dev/null`

Comment: Just use options.stdio of spawn method https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I asked this question on Node.js help
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/961

The answer is -

> You want fs.createWriteStream(). fs.openSync() just returns a file
>   descriptor.

So it would be:

```
k.stderr.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `silent` parameter when spawning the process like so:

```
const k = cp.spawn( "bash", [], { silent: true } );
```